# based on picklist value render a field

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I have bee trying to render a field based on lead status value like 'Cancel/Rejected'. if i select Cancel  value it should display field A, if i select value Reject it should display field B. please take a look at my visualforce page. What am i missing ?

Comment: Please add the parent components of your `selectList` to your original post (use the `edit` button)

Comment: sorry - you misunderstood me or I wasn't clear -- on the VF page, the parent apex:xxx components to your selectList - these columns must exist inside of something

Comment: I m using <apex:pageBlock>

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add my id for the output panel that i m using. That was the issue. Its a rookie mistake.